# Hide Shopify checkout button conditionally for specific product tags

Tags: shopify, product, checkout

I am using Shopify Dawn Theme 8.0 and need to hide the checkout button for certain products that are tagged with 'Quote Only'. I've added the bolded code below to the main-cart-footer.liquid file, but it's not hiding the checkout button when these tagged products are added to the cart.

```
<button
  type="submit"
  id="checkout"
  class="cart__checkout-button button"
  name="checkout"
  {% if cart == empty or product.tags contains 'quote only' %}
    disabled="disabled"
  {% endif %}
   form="cart">
 {{ 'sections.cart.checkout' | t }}
</button>
```

I have tried versions of this code in the cart-drawer.liquid and main-cart-items.liquid files as well. I have also tried having BARD and AIPRM for ChatGPT help me with this issue and the liquid, jQuery and JavaScript haven't worked either.

Comment: You can have 2 options

1. Hide buy now or add to cart button from product itself.
2. You can disable checkout button from crt page. 

You might need to loop through the cart products. Give a try with cart product loop

Still facing an issue let me know i will help you out.

Comment: Need to check about the cart object to get the cart data. you find more about cart object [here](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/cart)

Comment: @AtmiyaKolsawala How would code for a cart product loop, and where would I input that code?

Comment: @AtmiyaKolsawala I got the code to product loop, thanks for the insight!